# pass new params in existing params using spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I write deface for add new text field in order page and i want to update this record using spree default controller

vendor/spree/admin/_shipment/time_window.er.deface

```
<!-- insert_after 'div[data-hook="admin_shipment_form"] tr.edit-method div' -->

<% if @order.shipping_method_id.present? %>
<div class="field alpha five columns">
        <label><%= Spree.t(:fulfillment_time_window) %>:</label>

            <%= text_field_tag :fulfillment_time_window, @order.fulfillment_time_window %>  

        </div>

</div>
```

spree.rb

```
Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.shipment_attributes << :fulfillment_time_window
```

i want to update this field in order table

but it not pass this attribute in params

thanks in advance

Comment: Try this 
Spree::PermittedAttributes.shipment_attributes << :fulfillment_time_window

Comment: its in api, because i want to override backend/api/shipment_controller... that's why its Spree::Api::ApiHelpers.shipment_attributes << :fulfillment_time_window